# Custom `predict` method not working after serializing Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am encountering an issue with a custom `predict` method in a Keras model after serializing and reloading the model. Here's a simplified example of the problem:

I have a Keras model defined as follows:

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        tf.print('Hello from call')
        return self.dense1(inputs)
    
    def predict(self, inputs):
        tf.print('Hello from predict')
        return self(inputs)
```

I then train the model and save it:

```py
model = MyModel()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss="mean_squared_error")

# Train the model.
test_input = np.random.random((128, 32))
test_target = np.random.random((128, 1))
model.fit(test_input, test_target)

model.save("my_model")
reconstructed_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("my_model")

print('Normal model...')
y1 = model.predict(test_input)

print('Serialized model...')
y2 = reconstructed_model.predict(test_input)
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the custom `predict` method doesn't work as expected when using the serialized model. The `call` method is always called, and the custom `predict` method seems to be ignored.

How can I make the custom `predict` method work correctly when using the serialized model?

Comment: Any reason why you wanna override the predict method? (I assume you know that by doing so you discard all the [built-in logic](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/68f9af408a1734704746f7e6fa9cfede0d6879d8/keras/engine/training.py#L2452).) FYI, you might actually need to override `predict_step`, in case you have some goal while calling model.predict.

Comment: To extend my previous last sentence, see this [code example](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ipythonx/keras-stable-diffusion-image-to-prompts-tpu-vm), cell 25. In that example, `train_step` and `test_step` are overridden instead of overriding `fit` and `evaluate` methods respectively.

Comment: Thank you @Innat for your comments. I need to do some postprocessing after my prediction is done and before passing the result to the end user. I need to handle it within my serialized model and don't want to leave it for the user to handle.  overriding the predict_step is safer as you said, but even that is not solving my problem. I might make a mistake in saving or loading the models that doesn't serialize the predict function

Comment: I see. You ca use [callback](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/), where `predict_begin/end` method is available. And we can pass this callback while using model.predict. So you can use the callback's class method to define the post-processing logic.

Comment: I guess I understand the problem. for some specific project, I was asked to save the models on TF2.6, which apparently doesn't support the serialization of custom objects and overridden methods. with a higher version of TF, there is no issue.

Comment: Your code runs when I copy/paste it, so what's the problem? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

When you save and load a Keras model using model.save and tf.keras.models.load_model, it only saves the architecture, weights, and training configuration of the model. It does not save the custom methods you define in your model class, like the predict method in your case.
To address this issue, you can override the predict method in your custom model to ensure that it's used when calling predict on the loaded model.

refer - [Save and serialize modeles](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/serialization_and_saving) and [Custom layers and modeles](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing)

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np

    class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MyModel, self).__init__()
            self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

        def call(self, inputs):
            tf.print('Hello from call')
            return self.dense1(inputs)

        def predict(self, inputs):
            tf.print('Hello from custom predict')
            return self.call(inputs)

    model = MyModel()
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss="mean_squared_error")

    # Train the model.
    test_input = np.random.random((128, 32))
    test_target = np.random.random((128, 1))
    model.fit(test_input, test_target)

    # Save the model architecture, weights, and training configuration.
    model.save("my_model")

    # Load the model.
    reconstructed_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("my_model", 
    custom_objects={'MyModel': MyModel})

    print('Normal model...')
    y1 = model.predict(test_input)

    print('Serialized model...')
    y2 = reconstructed_model.predict(test_input)
```